# Break on file download on Chrome devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I see a lot of event listener breakpoints on the devtools, but not "download" or such.

I want to trigger a break on file download, is it possible through a setting or a program/JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`download` isn't an event in JavaScript, hence, you don't see it in the event listener breakpoints section. However, you can set a listener on XHR/Fetch calls, which would pause execution when the browser tried to fetch something.

More info:
https://www.canidev.tools/debug-xhr-fetch-calls/chrome

[image]